# Result of "Character.toUpperCase" is ignored

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, uppercase

this is my first question here and I've been desperate enough to ask it, since I haven't found any other posts related to my problems or which are related but too complex and don't relate to the actual code I have.

The thing is I want to ask the user for input and the input's letters shall be inverted, e.g: Hello to hELLO and vice versa. But the warning comes up "Result of 'Character.toUpperCase()' is ignored", any idea how to solve?

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
{
    if (Character.isLowerCase(word.charAt(i)))
    {
        Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(i));
    }
    else
    {
        Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to negate your current condition. You make a character uppercase if it is already uppercase.

Comment: @MCEmperor, ahahah I'm sorry, the other way around, I'm gonna edit it, thanks for the notice

Comment: @ernest_k, I'm taking Microsoft: DEV276x's Java course and we haven't taken that yet :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack overflow.
The problem is that the [`Character.toUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase-char-) won't overwrite the character in the string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "Hello";
    String wordInverted = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        //Get the char as a substring
        String subChar = word.substring(i, i+1);

        if (Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(i)))
        {
            subChar = subChar.toLowerCase();
        }
        else
        {
            subChar = subChar.toUpperCase();
        }

        wordInverted += subChar; //Add the newly inverted character to the inverted string
    }

    System.out.println(wordInverted);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, I didn't know that I had to use another string and add the inverted letters into that string. Much appreciated

Comment: Certainly, you don't have to put it into a new string, but it's a lot easier this way.